# IAM Policy for creating ECR repository - This action does not have an applicable resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-aws

I am working on a github action workflow that on a merge request creates the ECR repository for the given github repo before pushing the docker image. I am having some issues with granting the necessary permissions to the IAM policy. I have tried the following terraform code:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "github_actions_policy_ecr_push" {
  name   = "${var.namespace}github-actions-ecr-push"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.github_ecr_push.json
}


data "aws_iam_policy_document" "github_ecr_push" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
    ]
    
    resources = [
      "*",
    ]
  }
    
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
      "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
      "ecr:BatchGetImage",
      "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
      "ecr:PutImage",
      "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
      "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
      "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
      "ecr:ListImages",
      "ecr:DescribeImages",
      "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
      "ecr:CreateRepository",
      "ecr:PutLifecyclePolicy",
      "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:ecr:eu-west-1:${var.aws_management_account_id}:repository/*",
      "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:${var.aws_management_account_id}:repository/*",
    ]
  }
}
```

but when I apply it and check that the roles have been applied I get
 `This action does not have an applicable resource.` Shouldn't the policy have been applied for those resources? Any tips?

[image]

Comment: I think you are missing the principal here, and maybe even the `ecr:ReplicateImage` action.